# Is there a WIN32 registry search function?

Tags: winapi, registry

I started to write a program to recursively enumerate registry keys but then thought, hmm, there may be a registry search API function?  I can't seem to find one.  Is anyone aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no registry search function available via API.

Comment: Btw, there is also no real API to search for files!